# problem getting dynamic xml

Tags: asp.net, jquery, xml

i have an ASP.net page that generates dynamic xml but the get statement of a jquery ajax request won't recognize the file.  this solution worked with a php doc getting the dynamic xml. The asp.net page that generates xml works fine. The ajax request never succeeds. any ideas as to why much appreciated

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  Debug="true" ContentType="text/xml" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Xml" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
    <script runat="server">
        protected void Page_Load(object source, EventArgs e)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            // XML declaration
            XmlNode declaration = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration, null, null);
            doc.AppendChild(declaration);

            // Root element: article
            XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("statements");
            doc.AppendChild(root);

            string connStr = "";
            string sqlStr = "SELECT [title], [statement] FROM [a table]";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connStr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandText = sqlStr;

                    connection.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        int indexOftitle = dataReader.GetOrdinal("title");
                        int indexOfstatement = dataReader.GetOrdinal("statement");

                        while (dataReader.Read())
                        {
                            string title = (string)dataReader.GetValue(indexOftitle);
                            string statement = (string)dataReader.GetValue(indexOfstatement);

                            XmlElement xstatement = doc.CreateElement("statement");
                            root.AppendChild(xstatement);

                            XmlAttribute xtitle = doc.CreateAttribute("title");
                            xtitle.Value = title;
                            xstatement.Attributes.Append(xtitle);

                            XmlAttribute xtext = doc.CreateAttribute("text");
                            xtext.Value = statement;
                            xstatement.Attributes.Append(xtext);
                        }
                    }
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }


            doc.Save(Response.OutputStream);
        }
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "../data/genxml_docstate.aspx",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: parseXml
        });
    });
    function parseXml(xml) {
        alert("ok");
        var items = [];
        var header = 'some initial html'
        $(xml).find("statement").each(function () {
            var title = $(this).attr("title");
            var titleid = (title.substr(0, 8)).replace(" ", "_");
            items.push('<li id="' + titleid + '">' + title + '</li>');
        });

        $('#doclist').append(items.join(''));
        $("#doc_box_right").html(header);

        $(xml).find("statement").each(function () {
            var title = $(this).attr("title");
            var titleid = (title.substr(0, 8)).replace(" ", "_");
            var id = '#' + titleid;
            var statement = $(this).attr("text");
            $(id).css("cursor", "pointer");
            $(id).mouseover(function () {
                $(id).css("background-color", "gray");
                $("#doc_box_right").html('<h2>' + title + '</h2><p>' + statement + '</p>');
            });
            $(id).mouseleave(function () {
                $(id).css("background-color", "transparent");
                $("#doc_box_right").html(header);
            });
        });

    }
</script>
```

Comment: try succes like this success: function(data) { }

Comment: just put an alert inside the above success with the sytax i mentioned. and even you can with firebug .net panel whether u r getting data or not.

Comment: @gov - the ajax success function worked fine before...??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Chris , can you try firebug .net panel and see if you are getting results for the ajax...so that we can eliminate the issue.It shows the errors also if there are any.

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting the mime type of the response to `text/xml`, so the browser will not recognize it as  XML.

Make sure you add a:

```
Response.ContentType("text/xml");
```

before you save to the output stream.

Comment: @Chris , can  you try firebug .net panel and see if you are getting results for the ajax...so that we can eliminate the issue.It shows the errors also if there are any.

Comment: @put a break point also in the visual studio code , you can see if server is throwing any error , select break into execptions from visual studio option

Comment: then my comment should be answer :)